# Swift, Fire segue upon Orientation rotation

Tags: swift, orientation

Im trying to fire a segue based upon if the orientation is in landscape or portrait. This is what I am using, but its giving me an unrecongized selector error. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
 viewDidLoad(){
    UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showScoreCard:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

}



func showScoreCard {
    let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

    if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("scorecardSegue", sender: self)

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the colon at the end of your `showScoreCard` string, because the colon indicates that the method takes one argument.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know that about the colon. You rock!